# Make JSON loaded via function available to other functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to load JSON with a JS function, and then make the JSON objects that are loaded available to other functions in the same namespace. I've tried using return to serve up the array of objects retrieved, but that doesn't work. In the attached example, I've assigned the array of objects to a property in the namespaced object, but when I try to get that array of objects outside the main loadData function, all I get is null.

Here's my JS:

```js
var myObj = {
 jsonEndPoint: '/test/test.json',
 dataObjects: null
}

myObj.loadData = function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'test.json',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            myObj.dataObjects = data.apiResults[0].league.season.draft.rounds[0].picks;
            //console.log(myObj.dataObjects);
   

        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log('Data Load Error: ' + textStatus);
        }
    });

}()

myObj.displayData = function() {
 console.log(myObj.dataObjects)
}()
```

The full example can be seen here: http://zbl.me/test/index.html
The JSON file I'm loading is here: http://zbl.me/test/test.json

Comment: your `displayData` is called before the ajax is completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because **JavaScript is asynchronous in nature** — when you attempt to access the `myObj.dataObjects` in the `myObj.displayData` function, that object does not yet exist because the AJAX call has not been completed yet.

What you could do is that ensure that all functions that require newly added data from the AJAX call be run only when a `.done()` promise has been delivered from your AJAX call, by using `$.when()`. The logic is quite straightforward:

1. `myObj.loadData()` is now exclusively used to make the AJAX call. With regards to how we handle the done and fail events (which are previously `.success()` and `.error()` callbacks), we delegate that logic to the next function.
2. `myObj.displayData()` is now use to evaluate the promise returned by your AJAX call made with `myObj.loadData()`. You use `$.when()` to fetch the promise, and then simply chain `.done()` to deal with a successful call and `.fail()` to deal with the opposite :)

Here's your improved code:

```
var myObj = {
    jsonEndPoint: '/test/test.json',
    dataObjects: null
}

myObj.loadData = function () {
    // We return the AJAX object so that we can evaluate the state later
    // This is very simple :) 
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'test.json',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json'
    });
}()

myObj.displayData = function() {
    // Instead of using the deprecated .success() and .error()
    // ... we use .done() and .fail()
    $.when(myObj.loadData).done(function(data) {
        myObj.dataObjects = data.apiResults[0].league.season.draft.rounds[0].picks;
    }).fail(function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('Data Load Error: ' + textStatus);
    });
}()
```

If you are unsure, you can check the dummy code here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/5rbd2eqq/1/ I have used the built-in JSON response from JSfiddle to generate an artificial response, but the logic is exactly the same as yours.

Comment: All the answers addressed the race condition, but I selected your answer because your example of using $.when and $.done made the most sense in the context of what I'm trying to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your `displayData` method is called even before the ajax is completed. So you either need to call displayData in the success callback of ajax or change the structure a bit so that its easy to call.

Why don't you instead do something like this

```
var myObj = {
  jsonEndPoint: '/test/test.json',
  dataObjects: null,
  displayData: function() {
    console.log(this.dataObjects);
  },
  loadData: function() {
    $.ajax({
      context: this,
      url: 'test.json',
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        this.dataObjects = data.apiResults[0].league.season.draft.rounds[0].picks;
        console.log(myObj.dataObjects);
        this.displayData();
      },
      error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('Data Load Error: ' + textStatus);
      }
    });
  }
};

myObj.loadData();
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsbin.com/yoluli/1/edit?html,js,output)